# iTextSharp filling forms and creating multiple pages

Tags: vb.net, itext

I have following written codes

```
    Dim template As String = Server.MapPath("files/") & "2_paged_form.pdf"
    Dim newFile As String = Server.MapPath("exports/") & "newFile.pdf"

    Dim reader = New PdfReader(template)

    Dim output = New FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)

    Dim stamp = New PdfStamper(reader, output)
    stamp.AcroFields.SetField("client", "hello")
    stamp.AcroFields.SetField("name", "test test")
    stamp.AcroFields.SetField("address", "Hellocourt")
    stamp.AcroFields.SetField("postcode", "xx 3xx")
    stamp.AcroFields.SetField("dob", "11/02/1987")
    stamp.FormFlattening = True
    stamp.Close()

    output.Close()
    reader.Close()
```

I have managed to created a newfile.pdf with only onetime entry from 2_paged_form.pdf.

However I have multiple information to loop through so that newfile.pdf has multiple entries. for example newfile.pdf should have 10 pages with 5 different entries.

Could anyone help?

Comment: Are you trying to combine multiple PDFs into a single file? Or are you trying to fill out form fields in a single PDF that has multiple pages?

Comment: I am trying to fill two paged pdf form and later have it in single pdf file with multiple pages.

Comment: Anyone out there to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is documented on the official iText site and in the book.

If you prefer watching a video, you can watch [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6YwDME0Fl1c). You can try the examples [here](http://demo.itextsupport.com/itextsamples/). You need the entry "Fill, Flatten and Merge: how to do it correctly." The code for these examples can be found here: [FillFlattenMerge2](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/reporting/FillFlattenMerge2). Note that there's also a FillFlattenMerge1 example that demonstrates how *NOT* to do it. Please don't use that example ;-)

If you prefer reading a book, please download [Chapter 6 of "iText in Action - Second Edition"](http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf). You already know how to fill out one form (as described on page 185), you now want to merge different results. Again, there's an example on how *not* to do it (on page 190) and on how you *should* do it (on page 190-191).

I have never written a line of vb.net, but please look at this Java code as if it were pseudo code:

```
PdfCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
document.open();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos;
PdfReader reader;
PdfStamper stamper;
AcroFields fields;
while (data.hasMoreElements()) {
    // create a PDF in memory
    baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    reader = new PdfReader(SRC);
    stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, baos);
    fields = stamper.getAcroFields();
    MyData myData = data.nextElement();
    fields.setField("name", myData.getName());
    fields.setField("address", myData.getAddress());
    ...
    stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
    stamper.close();
    reader.close();
    // add the PDF to PdfCopy
    reader = new PdfReader(baos.toByteArray());
    copy.addDocument(reader);
    reader.close();
}
document.close();
```

As you can see, you need to create to fill the form resulting in a PDF that is kept in memory. Then you need to read this PDF from memory and add it to a `PdfSmartCopy` instance using the `addDocument()` method.

**P.S. 1:** What is wrong with the *bad* example? It results in bloated PDFs because the static content of the form is added redundantly as many times as you copy the form. `PdfSmartCopy` checks for redundant information and will add the static content only once.

P.S. 2: Why is there a *bad* way of doing it? The *bad* way of doing it, is actually a good way if the documents you are merging are all very different. In this case, the *bad* way is much faster and less memory-extensive and therefore actually the *good* way. It's only bad when you're merging documents that are very similar to each other, such as the same form filled out with different data sets.